# Query to find all the parent and child nodes of a given node in SQL

Tags: sql, parent-child, common-table-expression

I have seen many examples of the getting all the child nodes (including current node) in SQL using the CTE. Simple example is below:

```
;WITH #results AS
(
    SELECT  ChildId, 
            ParentId 
    FROM    History
    WHERE   ChildId= @selected
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.ChildId, 
            t.ParentId 
    FROM    History t
            INNER JOIN #results r ON r.ExpirationList = t.ParentId 
)
SELECT  *
FROM    #results;
```

The above query gives me all the child nodes for a given node. For eg: 
A -> B -> C -> D -> E and I pass @selected = "C", then I get results as **C** -> D -> E.

My question is how do I get the complete chain, irrespective of what I pass. 
If @selected = "D", then I want results as A -> B -> C -> **D** -> E and 
if @selected = "A", then I want results as **A** -> B -> C -> **D** -> E.

I want both parent and child nodes for the given nodes. Can someone help me with the query for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
;WITH #results1 AS
(
    SELECT  ChildId, 
            ParentId 
    FROM    History
    WHERE   ChildId= @selected
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.ChildId, 
            t.ParentId 
    FROM    History t
            INNER JOIN #results1 r ON r.ExpirationList = t.ParentId 
)
,#results2 AS
(
    SELECT  ChildId, 
            ParentId 
    FROM    History
    WHERE   ChildId= @selected
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.ChildId, 
            t.ParentId 
    FROM    History t
            INNER JOIN #results2 r ON t.ExpirationList = r.ParentId 
)
SELECT  *
FROM    #results1
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    #results2
```

Comment: Thanks Chriz for your suggestion. But It went in the infinite recursion.

Comment: This the error message I received. 
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 32767 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: I have altered the answer - apologies, your right it would have caused infinite recursion. You need to use two separate CTE's to prevent this, as shown above - then use a union to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

I combine the 2 CTEs (one for finding child and other for parents) into the common temp table and then pulled out the records from the same.

I referred to the below codeproject post which was helpful. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child

Thanks for your suggestions and responses.